# Align image caption with image in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I have a block image inserted as shown below:

```
[[myimage]]
image::fig1.png[align="center", title="My caption"]
```

Unfortunately, the image is centered but the caption is left-aligned. I also tried doing this:

```
[[myimage]]
.My caption
image::fig1.png[align="center"]
```

but the result does not change. How can I get the image caption to also be center-aligned?

I am generating HTML output with this command (using xhtml11 as backend makes no difference):

> asciidoc -v -a asciimath -d article -b html5 -o file.html file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS style sheet to do the alignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create directory `themes` in your working directory then download [this file](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/data/themes/default-theme.yml) into themes
2. Modify the captions align from left to center as below:

> caption:
>
> ```
> align: center
> ```

3. Specify theme file when generating pdf

> asciidoctor-pdf  ${adoc_file} -o ${output_pdf} -a pdf-stylesdir=themes
> -a pdf-style=custom-theme.yml